# Why can't I scale the UV coordinates of a texture larger than the image?

Tags: texturing, uv

I have a seamless carpet texture image that I want to use on a plane in my scene. I watched a bunch of videos and they all show the user scaling the uv coordinates so that they are larger than the image itself. In my situation, I am only able to scale the vertices to the bounds of the image. In other words, I can't scale them bigger than shown in the screenshot below...

[image]
What could I possibly be doing wrong?

Comment: With your cursor in the UV window press "S" to scale?

Comment: Yes, it will go smaller than that but not any larger.

Comment: Check in the UVs menu if Constraint to Image Bounds is selected.

Comment: Generally scaling UV coords in the UV editor is the same as adding Mapping node in the Node editor and adjusting values there. As to UV editor, there's Constrain To Bounds button in the UVs menu iirc, it's not enabled by default so you turned it on somehow

Comment: @MattFerndz yes that was it.  didn't even see that.  thanks!